# How to disable reading from configuration from bootstrap.yml in micronaut project?

Tags: micronaut

I have a Micronauts application with bootstrap.yml configuration that wan to read-only while running in the k8 cluster, but now when the test running from the bitbucket pipeline it is reading from bootstrap and throwing an error, so I want to enable this bootstrap only when it is running from my k8 cluster, how can we configure like that?

Comment: What in particular is being configured in `bootstrap.yml` that is problematic when running in your pipeline?  I ask because depending on what that is, the options to solve the problem might include not needing to conditionally evaluate `bootstrap.yml`.

Comment: In bootstrap I have the configurations to read from configmap and secret

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - we can create environment specific bootstrap.yml file like bootstrap-dev.yml, so it will work only in that specific environment.